# Replacing line in text file using C

Tags: c, database, text, edit

I have a question.
I am currently trying to write a simple database, and thereby trying to replace a line in the text file, when the viable gets updated in the program.

```
int totalsum(int imp,int is_out){

      int temp_int;
      char str[MAX_SIZE],int_buff[20];
      char *temp_char;
      char *checker = NULL;

      FILE *fptr;
      if ((fptr=fopen("data.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error in reading file\n");
      }else{

        fptr = fopen("data.txt", "r+");
        puts(str);
        while(fgets(str, MAX_SIZE, fptr)!=NULL ){
          checker = strstr(str,"//");
          if(!(str == checker)){
          checker = strstr(str,"sum");
          if (checker == str){
            temp_char = strtok(str, "sum =");
            if(atoi(temp_char)%10 ==0){
              if(!is_out)
              temp_int = atoi(temp_char) + imp;
            else
              temp_int = atoi(temp_char) - imp;
            }else{
              printf("Sum not divertable by 10, rounding down.");
              for(temp_int = atoi(temp_char);temp_int % 10 != 0;temp_int--);

                if(!is_out)
                  temp_int = temp_int + imp;
                else
                  temp_int = temp_int - imp;
            }
            _itoa(temp_int,int_buff,10);
            fputs(int_buff,fptr);
          }
        }
        }
        fclose(fptr);
      }
```

This is what I have as of now. And it does not edit the file, so is there something I'm doing wrong?

All help appreciated.

EDIT:
Not using Linux.

Comment: In which part did the OP sad that he's using Linux (Unix), Or I missing something in here ? Is there any SED version on Windows ? i just asking because i do not use Windows. If not, why marked as duplicate when there are only Linux based answers.

Comment: You're using `str` everywhere but never initialized it.

Comment: @Kotshi I did. `char str[MAX_SIZE]` - and for the reference, I've defined "MAX_SIZE" as to be 5000, since my text file, is not going to be larger than that.

Comment: Woups, I missed `fgets(str, MAX_SIZE, fptr)`, you shouldn't print it (`puts(str);`) before initializing it. By the way `char str[MAX_SIZE]` is called a definition.

Comment: Your program successfully write, but it writes at the end of the file.